# IntelliJ IDEA - Maven Can't Find JAVA_HOME After Java 11 Install

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu 18.04.  I've just installed Java 11 and have updated my `.bashsrc` file to set `JAVA_HOME` to the new JDK.  In the terminal I can run mvn clean install and it will build my d fine.  But in the IntelliJ terminal window, I get the following error when running a `mvn clean install`

> The `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run this program
>   NB: `JAVA_HOME` should point to a JDK not a JRE

In the IntelliJ terminal window this is the result of `echo $JAVA_HOME`

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11
```

Similarly, this is the result of `echo $PATH`

```
/home/myusername/.local/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11/db/bin
```

What do I need to do to have IntelliJ's version of maven recognize `JAVA_HOME`?  I've already set my Project SDK to JDK11.

Comment: Hi, I've not as I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04.  I have a dual boot with Windows 10 at the minute but I've not made any changes to the Java installation on Windows.

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11` directory contain the same directory tree structure as Oracle JDK or OpenJDK installed manually?

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same issue, except my Java version was shown as 1.8 after typing mvn -v in IDEA, but JAVA_HOME value was empty while it displayed correctly in Linux terminal. I`ve typed the following command in IDEA terminal

```
export JAVA_HOME=*path to Java 11*
```

This solved my problem. I think you could try the same without reinstall both Java and Maven.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the `Preferences > Build Tools > Maven > Runner`, and set the `JAVA_HOME` property manually.

Answer (score 1):

I messed around with this for a couple of hours yesterday but was unable to resolve the issue.  In the end, I completely uninstalled both Java and Maven and then reinstalled JDK8 and the latest Maven.  This appeared to fix the problem in that IntelliJ's command line was able to locate JAVA_HOME.

Here are the two resources I used to uninstall all Java and then reinstall JDK8, for anyone who is interested.

[How to completely uninstall Java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)

[How to install JDK on Ubuntu](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk8-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-desktops/)

I've yet to reinstall JDK11.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to update your "maven-javadoc-plugin" version.

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```